# Trying to find three words that appear in one file recursively

Tags: grep

I'm trying to search through my email backup  for an important email. It's a directory with subdirectories that contains a few thousand `.eml` file (on a Linux filesystem).
I would like to search for `.eml` text files that contain three words and to exclude one word.

First I tried searching for one word, then another with piping.

```
grep -R 'foo' ~/Directory/path | grep 'bar'
```

That didn't work, as it only returned files that contained the two words on the same line. I needed files that contained two words in the whole file.

I tried finding files that contained one word and piped the file contents to an output file.

```
grep -rIlZ  '.' -e 'foo' | xargs -0 cat > MyOutputFile
```

That was helpful, as I could see the context. But I needed to search for more than one word. Is it possbible to expand this to search for more than one word, and to exclude one word?

Comment: I use `grep -rw` for this sort of thing.

Comment: Similar Q&As: [Piped greps for looking inside files](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/531815) [grepping foo and bar](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/114049) [Search for text files where two different words exist (any order, any line)](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/67794) [Use grep to find all files in a directory with two strings](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68138) and the several duplicates linked to them.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose we want names of files that contain `foo` and `bar` but **not** `baz`.  In that case:

```
find . -type f -exec gawk '
  BEGINFILE{a=b=c=0}
  /foo/{a=1} /bar/{b=1} /baz/{c=1;nextfile}
  ENDFILE{if(a && b && !c)print FILENAME}' {} +
```

[Since you are on Linux, I assume you have ready access to GNU awk (gawk).]

Note that, in this approach, as few awk invocations as possible are started and each file is read only once.  No intermediate files are needed.  This should be efficient.

#### Example

Let's consider a directory with two files:

```
$ cat file1.eml 
foo and
bar only
$ cat file2.eml 
foo
and
bar
and
baz
```

If we run our command, it produces `./file1.eml` as the only file that meets the requirements:

```
$ find . -type f -exec gawk '
    BEGINFILE{a=b=c=0}
    /foo/{a=1} /bar/{b=1} /baz/{c=1;nextfile}
    ENDFILE{if(a && b && !c)print FILENAME}' {} +
./file1.eml
```

#### How it works

- `find` collects the list of regular files recursively and passes it `gawk`.
- `BEGINFILE{a=b=c=0}`

  At the start of every new file, this sets variables `a`, `b`, and `c` to zero (false).
- `/foo/{a=1}`

  If any line contains `foo`, set variable `a` to one. (true).
- `/bar/{b=1}`

  If any line contains `bar`, set variable `b` to one. (true).
- `/baz/{c=1;nextfile}`

  If any line contains `baz`, set variable `c` to one. (true).

  After any word to exclude if found, such as `baz` in our example, there is no point reading any more of the file.  So, we run `nextfile` to skip the rest of the lines and go immediately to ENDFILE.
- `ENDFILE{if(a && b && !c)print FILENAME}`

  At the end of each file, if `a` and `b` and *not* `c` (in awk `!` is logical-not) are all true, then print the file's name.

#### Non-GNU awk

If your awk doesn't have the nice `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` features, like `mawk`, you'd need to run one `awk` per file:

```
find . -type f -exec mawk '
  /foo/{a=1} /bar/{b=1} /baz/{c=1;exit}
  END{if(a && b && !c) print FILENAME}' {} \;
```

or (hat tip: [Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton)):

```
awk 'FNR==1 { if (a && b && !c) print fname; fname=FILENAME; a=b=c=0 } /foo/{a=1} /bar/{b=1} /baz/{c=1}   END{if(a && b && !c) print FILENAME}' *.eml
```

or, with recursive search:

```
find . -type f -exec awk 'FNR==1 { if (a && b && !c) print fname; fname=FILENAME; a=b=c=0 } /foo/{a=1} /bar/{b=1} /baz/{c=1}   END{if(a && b && !c) print FILENAME}' {} +
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Both excellent suggestions!  Answer updated with the `./` precaution and the `nextfile` trick.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Excellent suggestion, again!  Answer updated with `{c=1;exit}`

Comment: What I learned is the one thing you didn't explicitly document in this great answer `{} +` vs `{} \;`

Comment: @AaronMcMillin `{} +` puts many file names on each command line.  `{} \;` puts only one on each command line (requiring many more invocations of the command with all the associated overhead of starting and ending processes).

Comment: See also [grep'ping files for multiple strings (not necessarily on the same line)](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/466197) for a generalisation (though without the negative matches) of that approach for a given list of patterns.

Comment: @EdMorton Answer updated with your `FNR==1...` code.

Comment: @EdMorton Ugh!  Yes!  Corrected (I think).

Comment: @John1024 Thanks for the very clear answer, this enabled me to tailor the command to my needs. I didn't find what I was looking for, but at least I can confirm that it's not there.

Answer (score 2):

Try `find -exec` with `grep -q`:

```bsh
find /my/path -name "*.eml" \
  -exec grep -F -q "word1" {} \; \
  -exec grep -F -q "word2" {} \; \
  -exec grep -F -q "word3" {} \; \
  ! -exec grep -F -q "word4" {} \; \
  -print
```

- `grep -q` returns only status code
- Leave out the `-F` from `grep` if you want to search patterns instead of words
- Add `-w` to `grep` to match only whole words: match `word` but not `someword`.
- `find` chains the `-exec` commands and stop when one of it fails (when `grep -q` returns an error code)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an approach like:

```
grep -rIlZe foo . |
  xargs -r0 grep -lZe bar |
  xargs -r0 grep -LZe baz |
  xargs -r0 cat > MyOutputFile
```

That is, feed the list of files generated by the first `grep` to `xargs -r0` to pass to the next `grep` which further refines the list.

Note the `-L` option for the last `grep` which is like `-l` except that it reports the files where no match is found, so we end up with the files that contain `foo` and `bar` and *not* `baz`.

The `-r` and `-I` are only needed or the first `grep`. The latter ones will get lists of regular files as arguments (with binary files already filtered out by `-I` on the first `grep`), not directories for which to `r`ecurse in.

That means the contents of files could end up being read several times, which is not very efficient, but `grep` implementations being generally a lot faster than `awk` implementations, and also with the fact that since all 4 commands above are started in parallel, some of that processing will be performed concurrently by several processors and with data already cached in memory, it's likely to be faster than `awk`-based ones.

Comment: Nicely done combination of `grep` and `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste this piece of code into a new bash script file, save it and do `chmod +x <file>` then run it in your terminal to list all files that contain **"foo"** and **"bar"** and don't contain **"rab"** strings:

```
#!/bin/bash
function notcontain {
        for FILE in $(find . 2> /dev/null); do
                if ! grep "rab" $FILE > /dev/null 2>&1; then
                        echo $FILE
                fi
        done
}
    
for FILE in `notcontain`; do
        if grep "foo" $FILE > /dev/null 2>&1 | grep "bar" $FILE > /dev/null 2>&1; then
                echo $FILE
        fi
done
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, however, that this would locate files that contain _either_ `foo` or `bar` whereas the OP wants to look for files that contain _both_ `foo` _and_ `bar` (and a third word, actually  ;) ...)

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks for the tips. I edited the answer.